# Must `throw nullptr` be caught as a pointer, regardless of pointer type?

Tags: c++, exception, language-lawyer

The following program throws `nullptr` and then catches the exception as `int*`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    try {
        throw nullptr;
    }
    catch(int*) {
        std::cout << "caught int*";
    }
    catch(...) {
        std::cout << "caught other";
    }
}
```

In Clang and GCC the program successfully prints `caught int*`, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/789639qbb

However in Visual Studio 16.11.2 the program prints `caught other`. Is it a bug in MSVC?

Comment: Other than testing the compiler's conformance with the C++ standard, why would anyone *want* to `throw nullptr;`?

Comment: @dan04 'Cause it's easy? Same as `throw 0;` or `throw "bug";`. Quick and dirty. (Very dirty.)

Comment: @dan04: because we can! The language provides the feature, so why not use it? I also love writing `volatile const unsigned const long unsigned int volatile long x = 5;`, because it will make the next developer reflect whether C++ is really the right language to use :-)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Looks like a bug in Visual Studio, according to the standard [[except.handle]](https://eel.is/c++draft/except.handle#3.4):

> A handler is a match for an exception object of type `E` if
>
> [...]
>
> - the handler is of type `cv T` or `const T&` where `T` is a `pointer` or `pointer-to->member` type and `E` is `std​::​nullptr_t`.

Comment: Thanks. I reported MSVC bug: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Not-standard-handling-of-throw-nullptr/1571545

Comment: Corresponding GCC [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58796). This was fixed in GCC 7.

Comment: @alex_noname thanks for the link. This makes me totally relaxed. Whenever PM or PO talk to me next time, I'll refer to this bug and tell them that it'll not take 2 weeks, but 4 years to fix the issue.